Stuck after pressing Ubuntu logo in lower left corner
I've encountered a problem while live testing Ubuntu from a bootable USB where after pressing the Ubuntu logo in the lower left corner of the dock, I'm stuck in the "Show application" menu (I'm sorry I couldn't describe it much better).
When you press the Ubuntu logo in the lower left corner of the screen it typically shows all of your installed applications but in my case while live testing it, it gets stuck there. I can move the mouse and I can open other apps that are pinned in the dock but they wouldn't show because it's stuck/freezes.
For the solutions or what I did, all I could do was to redo the entire live testing to I would get out of the stuck menu.
How do I prevent it from getting stuck in the "Show applications" menu?
I have a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3, 16GB RAM, Ryzen 5 CPU and Nvidia GTX 1650.
Thank you very much!

Unfortunately this seems to be a case in which the Ubuntu live session is unable to do a complete job of being a live session because it apparently is freezing because you haven't installed the proprietary graphics driver for your Lenovo Ideapad's Nvidia GTX 1650 GPU.
If everything else works OK in the live session I recommend installing Ubuntu on your laptop, and in the "Updates and other software" screen select the option to Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats.

Alternatively you can leave this option unchecked and install the Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers automatically after booting to your new Ubuntu installation by running sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot

Some live USB applications such as Rufus and mkusb create a dedicated persistent storage file or partition alongside the live system. This allows the live system to save files and installed software across reboots. The live Ubuntu environment itself still operates using a read-only squashfs file system for the core system files. This is inherent to how Ubuntu live environments are designed, regardless of the tool used to create them. The addition of persistent storage enables saving some changes, but it does not allow for modifications to the core system files necessary for fully integrating drivers, so hardware-specific drivers (like the Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers) may not function optimally or as expected. For tasks that require a persistent driver installation, a full Ubuntu installation on a USB storage device or an internal drive is more reliable.

Everything works while live testing, bluetooth, wifi and battery modes were all working but is it possible to install the proprietary drivers for Nvidia while live testing? As much as possible I want to see and fix every problem before I commit to a full install of Ubuntu

Thank you for the answer @karel. I'll just probably decide to do a full Ubuntu install since I can't make core changes based on what you've said.
